# ifndef, define, endif

Tags: c++

Я не понимаю, то ли я криворук, то ли лыжи не скачут.

Файл `C.h`

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H
int QWE = 1;
#endif /* C_H */
```

Файл `B.h`

```
#include "C.h"
```

Файл `A.h`

```
#include "B.h"
```

Почему компилятор ругается на LNK2005   "int QWE" (?QWE@@3HA) уже определен в A.obj, если были использованы ifndef, define, endif?
Пробовал качать другую версию MSVS, пробовал писать `#pragma once`, но ошибка остаётся. Ткните носом, где я туплю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы подключаете (пусть опосредованно) `c.h` в разные `.cpp`-файлы, вот у вас и получается в двух разных файлах *определение*

```
int QWE = 1;
```

Вот линковщик и ругается, встречая две переменные с одним именем в двух разных местах, не зная, что ему выбрать...

Объявите переменную в `.h`-файле как

```
extern int QWE;
```

а в *одном* `.cpp`-файле определите

```
int QWE = 1;
```

Так вы перестанете нарушать *правило одного определения*.

Answer (score 1):

Назначение include guards `#ifndef/#define/#endif` - защитить ваш код от ошибок вида

```
#include "C.h"
...
#include "C.h"
```

т.е. от множественного включения одного и того же заголовка в *одну и ту же единицу трансляции* (явно или опосредованно, через другие заголовки). Такое множественное включение в общем случае приведет к ошибкам *компиляции*.

Include guards, вопреки вашим ожиданиям, не имеют никакого отношения к защите от ошибок множественного определения переменных или функций *во всей программе*, т.е. между *разными* единицами трансляции (вызывающих ошибки *линковки*). От вашей ошибки include guards никак не защищают и не должны защищать, поэтому ваше удивление "Почему компилятор ругается на LNK2005, ... если были использованы ifndef, define, endif?" совершенно не оправданно.

Либо перестаньте совать *определения* переменных в заголовочный файл (т.е. пойдите по "классическому" пути с `extern`). Либо воспользуйтесь свойством С++17 и просто сделайте вашу переменную `inline`

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H
inline int QWE = 1;
#endif /* C_H */
```