# Ошибка multiple definition of... при подключении моей библиотеки в любой h файл

Tags: c++, qt

[Вот библиотека](https://github.com/elfenliedmyr/MainClickLib)

Когда я подключаю ее в любой файл h получаю ошибку переопределения, что интересно что если подкл. к cpp файлам все нормально, это очень неудобно потому что надо часто делать классы состоящие из h и cpp и подкл. в сpp это бред.
Немного дополню описание вопроса. [Вот видос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fQPMlsBonM&t=305s) с подкл. библиотеки, правда я незнаю будет ли он работать, ибо я в своей библиотеке делал, позже делал подкл. Open Cv3 Поэтому возможно в pro файл надо добавить пути openCv но они есть в profile самой библиотеки. Например вот класс:

```
#ifndef MCONTROLLER_H
#define MCONTROLLER_H

    #include <clicklib.h> //тут ошибка
    //#include <qobject.h>
    class MController
    {

    public:
        MController();
    };

    #endif // MCONTROLLER_H

#include "mcontroller.h" //а тут если подкл не будет будет ошибка

MController::MController()
{

}
```

А в новой версии, которую я написал уже увеличилось не 5 а 25
[image: Вот ошибки]

Comment: Подключение хедеров в .cpp - вовсе не бред. Именно так и нужно поступать в 99% случаев, если есть такая возможность. А чтобы ответить, нужны детали.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос

Comment: По ссылке какая-то свалка бинарных файлов... Где clicklib_global.h?

Comment: Вот https://github.com/elfenliedmyr/MainClickLib/blob/master/ClickLib/clicklib_global.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так у вас в заголовочном файле `clicklib.h` сидят определения переменных

```
int startTime = 0;
...
SystemTrey* st;
```

Разумеется, будут ошибки линковки с множественными определениями.

[Та же ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781658/ifndef-define-endif)

Comment: Спс за ответ, так а что ж мне конкретно с этим "счастьем" делать? Эти переменные мне как бы там надо. Делаю их inline не компилируется библиотека, выношу в отдельный h файл с подкл. не помогает. Читаю,  спс