# Уже определен но нигде не определен

Tags: c++

ImageRenderer.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _IMAGE_RENDERER_H_
#define _IMAGE_RENDERER_H_
#include "mainUtils.h"

struct lTexture
{
    u32 id;
    const char* name;
    SDL_Texture* sdl_tx;
};

std::vector<lTexture> vvLoadedTextures;

void draw_background(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int w, int h);
bool draw_image(const char* t, int w, int h, SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer);
#endif
```

Core.cpp

```
#include "ImageRenderer.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // code...
    for (int i = 0; i < vvLoadedTextures.size(); i++)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(vvLoadedTextures[i].sdl_tx);
    }
    // another code
    return 0;
}
```

Во время линковки мне выбивает ошибку мол "LNK2005: vvLoadedTextures уже определен в Core.obj", везде облазил, нигде не нашел где может оно повторно объявляться.

Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Что значит "где"? Вы включили свой заголовочный файл `ImageRenderer.h` в несколько разных `.cpp` файлов - вот вам и готово несколько определений `vvLoadedTextures`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781658/ifndef-define-endif

Comment: Что такое `std::vector<lTexture> vvLoadedTextures;`, как не *определение*? А их лучше в заголовочные файлы не помещать...

Comment: кроме этого препроцессорная директива `#pragma once` применяется для тех же целей, что и добавление `#include guards` (#ifndef _IMAGE_RENDERER_H_ и т.д.) для однократного подключения. Так что:
    #ifndef _IMAGE_RENDERER_H_
    #define _IMAGE_RENDERER_H_
у вас является лишней писаниной.

Comment: @Harry А надо, ибо этот вектор должен передаваться между CPP файлами со всеми данными которые были внесены в него в других CPP файлах.

Comment: @AnT этот заголовочный файл был включен только в ImageRenderer.cpp который содержит в себе функции и в Core.cpp. При этом Core.cpp и ImageRenderer.cpp никак между собой не связанны.

Comment: Глобальные переменные - вообще вещь нехорошая. Но если уж так нужно - то добавьте `inline`, или используйте `extern` с *определением* в одном из .cpp-файлов.

Comment: Не ответ, но зачем вам и `#pragma once`, и include guard? Одного из двух достаточно.

Comment: @DezMax Не понял. Что значит "никак не связаны"? Ваши `.cpp` файлы входят в один проект - вот вам и множественное определение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас `vvLoadedTextures` определен в заголовочном файле, и при этом он не `inline`.

Напишите `inline std::vector<lTexture> vvLoadedTextures;`